# C socket recvmsg, packets are missing

Tags: android, c, linux, sockets

I have a problem with receiving UDP packets. My environment is running Android 2.1 on ARMv7. With C socket programming, I use ***recvmsg*** to receive packets from kernel but occasionally there  are some packet loss events. The sender and receiver are in the same LAN so it's no doubt that packets shouldn't lose. And I proved it via **Wireshark**.

However, after I replaced ***recvmsg***  with ***recvfrom*** to receive packets, packet loss event didn't occur anymore.

I'm sure the return value of ***recvmsg*** is always more than 0, meaning no error happens.

Is it possible that some packets are dropped in kernel-space only when using ***recvmsg*** ?

Comment: Are all packets sent from the same source? Perhaps multiple sources send packets to your one socket?

Comment: What is the problem with recvfrom?

Comment: yes, all packets are sent from the same source.

Comment: @mathk ***recvfrom*** doesn't have any problem but recvmsg does. once I use recvmsg   a few packets get lost. So I'm very curious about the difference between ***recvfrom*** and ***recvmsg***

Comment: I understand, I think the best if you really want to know the difference is to have a look at the source code in the kernel. A quick look into the libc tell me that both function are two different syscall. So have a look at the android kernel syscall to step toward the answer your seeking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. UDP is unreliable. If dropping of UDP datagrams is creating a problem, then something is very wrong with your design.

Comment: The packets aren't dropped on the network, as he proved with Wireshark, so he shouldn't be seeing lost packets at all. Lost packets can lead to performance issues in properly designed systems, so you want to minimize them, especially if you're the cause.

Comment: He isn't seeing lost packets, he's seeing lost datagrams. UDP datagrams can be lost, that's just the nature of UDP. Losing packets on a network is just one way datagrams can be lost. Sure, if you're the cause, you should do something about it. But no matter what you do, UDP datagram loss will always be possible. That's just the nature of UDP.

Comment: It's is not normal, when packets lost in the system. It is possible, but rather because of the stress conditions.

Comment: sure, UDP datagram loss will always be possible, but I'm wandering why UDP datagram could lose in system. (Buffer overflow?)

Comment: @Corey: Any reason or no reason. Anything that wishes to may discard IP datagrams for any reason. If that IP datagram happens to contain a UDP datagram, the UDP datagram is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Check your socket for drops via `cat /proc/net/udp`.

Answer (score -1):

This [recv man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/recvmsg.html) seems to indicate that **recvmsg does not block**, while **recvfrom does block**, at least by default. It's possible that you are calling recvmsg and there are no packets available at that moment. If you called it repeatedly I suppose you might see all your packets eventually just like you did in wireshark.

Comment: That is not at all what it 'seems to indicate'. What it *actually says* is this: 'If no messages are available at the socket and O_NONBLOCK is not set on the socket's file descriptor, `recvfrom()` blocks until a message arrives. If no messages are available at the socket and O_NONBLOCK is set on the socket's file descriptor, recvfrom() function fails and sets errno to [EAGAIN] or [EWOULDBLOCK].'